# Qt Creator + OpenCV: Program runs from .exe but not from editor

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

Well, I need to start working with OpenCV and as I'm used to working with QtCreator, I'm trying to make it all work together. I downloaded the latest OpenCV version, and compiled it with MinGW. Then, I created this little console project to try it out. Below is the `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = OpenCV_test4
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\Librerias\\opencv2.3.1\\release\\include
LIBS += -LC:\\Librerias\\opencv2.3.1\\release\\lib \
    -lopencv_core231.dll \
    -lopencv_highgui231.dll \
    -lopencv_imgproc231.dll \
    -lopencv_features2d231.dll \
    -lopencv_calib3d231.dll
```

Here is the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // read an image
    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("img.jpg");
    // create image window named "My Image"
    cv::namedWindow("OpenCV Window");
    // show the image on window
    cv::imshow("OpenCV Window", image);
    // wait key for 5000 ms
    cv::waitKey(5000);

    return a.exec();
}
```

(I have tried this code with and without the `QCoreApplication` lines)

The deal is: It links and builds, and when runs from QtCreator only a terminal window called `C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator_process_stub.exe` appears with the line *"Press RETURN to close this window..."*

But, if I run the .exe from the project folder, it runs perfectly!! Why is QtCreator unable to launch the application? I found this really strange, and I would appreciate any hint about this. It's really not THAT important, but it is kind of a pain to have to run the .exe manually every time I change something to check how it works.

Thanks for your time :)

**Additional Info:**

- I have tried both debug and release versions, the problem is the same in both of them.
- Debugging does not work, it never stops at any breakpoint.
- I'm running on Windows 7 Proffesional x64

---

SOLVED, I don't really know what I did, it suddenly worked and keeps working, I wish I could tell you how I fixed it but I have no idea, such a weird thing :(

Comment: Add the C++ tag to give your question better visibility.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem : debug and release work perfectly running the exe directly but not with Qt Creator... (imread always returning an empty image) Did you, or someone else, figured out what is the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check Projects -> Run Settings -> Run in terminal. It have to be enabled, but seems to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have met same problem with QtCreator and OpenCL under Linux. Simple test program works after start from terminal and it does not work after start from the QtCreator. 
I found the cause was hardcoded LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the project's run environment settings. I had dropped it to empty string and this had fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the following environment: Raspbian, Qt, openCV and a gui application.

old-ufo recommendation worked for me:
- First, enable "Run in terminal", which failed
- Then, disable "Run in terminal", which allowed me to correctly debug my app.

I understand that this is not scientific.